# AngularJS architecture: shared utilities across directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the best practice for sharing functionality across multiple directives? Simple use case:

```
directive('colorInput', function() { // user inputs a hex value })
directive('stringInput', function() { // user inputs a string })
```

And lets say there's an HTML user assistance bubble that appears when the user focuses into an input. We might then have a function that positions the bubble relative to the input like so:

```
function setBubble(input, bubble) { // position the bubble }
```

Is there a way to maintain modularity and encapsulation? Or would this have to go into an angular service or the like? Thanks!

Comment: Services are not about UI, and dont contain any DOM manipulation code. Depending upon your requirement you would have to use service or directives itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use controller instead. Checkout the section **Creating Directives that Communicate** in [Angular Directive Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). create a controller named inputGroupController that both your directives *require* it. Whenever user focus on an input, call baseInputController.setBubble(input, bubble). Take this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cUhxYmf9b3S1dsRjQXaG?p=preview